# Getting train test data from Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras as follows.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(samplewise_center=True,
    samplewise_std_normalization=True, validation_split=0.30
                               )
```

Then `.flow` statement to obtain train and test split as follows.

```
train_iterator = datagen.flow(x, y, subset='training')
test_iterator = datagen.flow(x, y, subset='validation')
```

Here `x` represents images with a shape `(588, 120, 120, 1)` and `y` represents `multiclass` output `(588, 4)`.

In `(588, 120, 120, 1)` shape input data, there are total `588` samples each with a shape of `(120, 120, 1)`. The output is having 4 classes.

Then I train and test my CNN with the following code.

```
history =model.fit_generator(train_iterator,
                             
                              epochs=10,
                              validation_data=test_iterator,
                              callbacks=callbacks_list) 


pred_test = model.predict(test_iterator, steps=len(test_iterator), verbose=0)
```

**My question is:**
How can I access the test data (both x and y) which `test_iterator` uses for prediction.

Answer (score 1):

`flow()` returns an iterator yielding tuples of (x, y), you can access elements using `test_iterator.next()`.

Comment: Will it gives me test data set samples one by one?

Comment: yes, each time you will call next() function it will iterate to the next element

Comment: My test set has 176 samples, but test_iterator.next() gives me 32 samples. How can I get all my 176 samples of test data using test_iterator.next()

Comment: your batch size is 32?

Comment: that is default batch size in datagen.flow.

Comment: you can use batch size 176 to get all the samples.

Comment: i'm not sure, maybe its an infinite generator so you will get elements after each next() function call. you will have to call next until you get 176 samples from it.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI. In the ImageDataGenerator you have set samplewise_center=True,
samplewise_std_normalization=True,. If this is what you want you must FIRST fit the generator to accumulate the statistics of the input data so first do

```
datagen.fit(x)
```

Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)